# Using ImageMagick to Thumbnail an Image depending on Aspect Ratio

Tags: resize, imagemagick, thumbnails, aspect-ratio

So I have done some research on this and I couldn't find an appropriate answer and wondered if there was even a way to do this:

Basically I need to create thumbnails for large files (adobe cs files, image files, videos, etc) after they are being uploaded to a website. I have done this part and it actually works great using some multithreading techniques to not make the user wait after upload is done.

Currently I am resizing all thumbnails to a square size of 250x250. This is the IM command:

```
convert -quiet examplefile.extn 
-thumbnail x250 
-resize 250x< 
-background white 
-gravity center 
-crop 250x250+0+0 
+repage 
-unsharp 0x.5 
-quality 80 
-flatten 
thumbnail.jpg
```

Looks awesome on videos and psd files ;) Ok so it turns out some website requirements have changed (dontya love it when that happens?) and now I need to resize the image based on their aspect ratios. The conditions are:

If height/width > 1, set the thumbnail WIDTH to 250 with freedom to height (max 500).
If height/width <= 1, set the thumbnail HEIGHT to 250 with freedom to width (max 500).

Is this possible? Any pointers, suggestions, alternatives greatly appreciated as I continue to research myself...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resize options are here: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry

```
convert -quiet examplefile.extn -thumbnail 250x250 +repage -unsharp 0x.5 -quality 80 thumbnail.jpg
```

Your code seems a bit over complicated - try the above which will keep the aspect ratio and the maximium dimension will be 250px.

If you want to do something more complicated I would do it outside IM and pass the width and height dimension to the command as variables.

```
-thumbnail {$width}x{$height}
```

Comment: I kinda wanted to avoid another IO operation, but it looks like Im gonna have to settle for computing the size outside IM. Thanks also for the advice on shortening my IM command =)